# Node's fs module unlinkSync() won't delete my file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

In order to encrypt the files I save some of their info to `info.json` and then encrypt that. That creates a new file named `info.dat`. I then attempt to delete the original `info.json` file because it has decryption keys and file names. But, for some reason it doesn't delete. I have a 'vice-versa like' process for decryption where I have to delte `info.dat` and that seems to work fine. What I think the problem might be (I could be wrong) is when the `info.json` file is getting info written to it, the function to delete it is also being called, causing nothing to happen. Is this the issue? If not what is?

```js
const fs = require('fs'), encryptor = require('file-encryptor'), info = require('./info');

const dir = './Encrypted Files/';

const encryptFiles = () => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        let key = 'lol';

        files.forEach(file => {
            const date = new Date();
            const name = `encrypted~${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}~${date.getTime()}.dat`;

            encryptor.encryptFile(dir + file, dir + name, key, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                } else {
                    console.log(`Successfully encrypted '${file}'`);

                    info.key = key;

                    info.files.push({
                        enName: name,
                        deName: file,
                    });

                    fs.writeFile('./info.json', JSON.stringify(info), (err) => {if (err) throw err});
                }
            });

            fs.unlinkSync(dir + file);
        });

        infoJSON.encrypt(key);
    });
};

const infoJSON = {
    clear: () => {
        const clearInfo = {"files": [], "key": ""}
    
        fs.writeFile('./info.json', JSON.stringify(clearInfo), (err) => {if (err) throw err});
    },

    encrypt: (key) => {
        encryptor.encryptFile('./info.json', './info.dat', key, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
        })

        fs.unlinkSync('./info.json', (err) => {if (err) throw err}); //THIS Doesn't work!!!
    },

    decrypt: (key) => {
        encryptor.decryptFile('./info.dat', './info.json', key, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });

        fs.unlinkSync('./info.dat');
    }
};

const decryptFiles = (key) => {
    infoJSON.decrypt(key);

    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            let fileName = '';

            info.files.forEach(fileInfo => {
                (fileInfo.enName == file) && (fileName = fileInfo.deName)
            });

            encryptor.decryptFile(dir + file, dir + fileName, info.key, (err) => {
                (err) ? console.log(err) : console.log(`Successfully decrypted '${file}'`);
            });

            fs.unlinkSync(dir + file);
        });
    });

    infoJSON.clear();
};

//encryptFiles()
//decryptFiles("lol")

/*
encryption: encrypt files => add encryption info to info.json => encrypt info.json
decryption: decrypt info.json => decrypt files => clear info.json
*/
```

Comment: Could be trying to delete the file before the callback is done. Use a promise to await the encryption.

Comment: Yep, you're not handling your asynchronous operations correctly and thus are trying to delete the file before you're done processing it.  You shouldn't be attempting to delete the file until AFTER the last completion callback has been called in the function where you're reading/writing to those files.

Comment: @jfriend00 Async function or promises haven't worked. Any other ideas? Or could you give me a code example on what to do?

Comment: Well, they work just fine when they are written correctly.  For us to help you with what you tried, you would have to add that code that you tried to the end of your question and then we could help you solve problems with that.  We prefer here not to just write your code for you, but for you to attempt to educate yourself on the topic, work up a way to do it, write that code, attempt to debug it yourself and then post your code here when you get stuck on a specific problem so you're asking about how to do X rather than asking us to write your code for you.